# WSDL Object model

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl

I'm using the WSDL object model (WOM) along with XSOM for a project of mine. The WOM gives me a way to drill down and look at messages and the message types which are element declarations. However, I am unable to find a way to parse the simple and complex types. The APIs are tricky. There seems to be some kind of a connection between WOM and XSOM. I'd really appreciate it if you could tell me how I can parse the simple and the complex types in my .wsdl file.

Comment: What platform are you using? Java? Which package are you using? Do you really think you gave enough information for someone to help you?

Comment: Apparently "WSDL Object Model" refers to something specific. See https://wom.dev.java.net/.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use EASY WSDL : http://easywsdl.ow2.org/

I can parse both WSDL 1.1 and 2.0 unlike WOM which can only parse 1.1.

It's really a very simple api try it!

Answer (score 0):

You don't parse the simple and complex types with WOM, but with XSOM. You need to pass SaxEvents to XSOM in order to retrieve the bit of XSD code.

You can't do this with EasyWSDL, as there's a bug in the toolbox which makes it unable to retrieve the defined types and elements. Even when you're doing it from a PartImpl object.